# Hyphens in route, works with link, doesn't work directly

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to use hyphens in an URL route. In ASP.NET Core MVC. I setup a default MVC template.

The only thing I change is to add this first line:

```
[Route("hello-dude")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now, when I got to test the project, I click privacy and it shows the correct page and URL. (http://localhost:44386/hello-dude)

But when I go to the address bar and put that in manually, click enter, I get "site cannot be reached".

What is going on here?

Startup.Cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication8
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe non-hyphen routes also don't work when entering directly?

Comment: Or maybe you are confusing en-dashs, em-dashs, hyphens and all those similar looking characters? You could try pasting the hypen (or whatever it is) into [this online detector](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html).

Comment: I dont even put the url in. I click privacy, then go to the addresses bar and click enter on the url already there.

Comment: I have created a test demo on my side and it works well. Could you please share the startup.cs route configure and your layout view codes?

Comment: Ok. Startup.cs added to question.

Comment: I still couldn't reproduce your issue. I guess you may used the wrong url in browser. Could you please check your url is as same as the view generated url?